# How to reduce usage of nVidia's nvwgf2umx.dll in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, cpu-usage, nvidia, win2d

All of my UWP apps are calling **WaitForSingleObjectEx** and **ReleaseSemaphore** methods in **nvwgf2umx.dll** library if I use **Win2d** or **UI.Composition** API.

Visual Studio Profiler reports me that about **80%** of CPU usage is about nVidia library.

I couldn't google anything about this issue and it's driving me mad.

[image]

I tried to install many versions of GPU driver but none helped.

If I switch to Intel GPU - no issues with CPU at all, but I need nVidia's acceleration.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This series of posts are old but still apply to more modern APIs and GPU hardware.  Hopefully they will help you understand more about the timing behavior you are seeing after submitting a GPU rendering workload to the driver.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2008/03/14/understanding-gpu-performance/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2008/03/31/an-elf-in-a-box/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2008/04/02/lost-in-translation/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2008/04/07/how-to-tell-if-you-are-cpu-or-gpu-bound/